# Amazon ec2 change the access key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm using amazon EC2 instance. Which is an Ubuntu server. I'm using the key which created with the instance for long time. For security reason I want to change the key. Simmply have to asign new key and disable the older key access. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by following steps.

- First create a new key pair on AWS console. Example name "beta"
- Then download the key file "beta.pem"
- Change the file permision of key to 400 `sudo chmod 400 beta.pem`
- Then generate publick key file with following command. `ssh-keygen -y -f beta.pem > beta.pub`
- Then go to ".ssh" directory on home directory `cd /home/ubuntu/.ssh/`
- There edit the "authorized_keys" file and add the new key on next
  line
- It will be like follows

> ssh-rsa [your public key] [key name]

- Older key can be removed by removing he related lines.